# mycoeiroinkの作動方法について知りたい。

Tags: プログラミング言語

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]mycoeiroinkで https://coeiroink.com/mycoeiroink/list?i=5 ゆっくり実況みたいなものを作ろうと思ってますがURLから好きな声の方を選び配布ページに飛んでとりあえずリポジトリをダウンロードしますが(私がダウンロードしたものhttps://iro-alphascape.booth.pm/items/4946656とhttps://kikyohiroto1227.wixsite.com/kikoto-utau/mahiro)それでダウンロードした後どうやって開くのかがわからないですよ。https://zenn.dev/kun432/scraps/8e963a8a4948b2
で使い方乗ってるのですがターミナルでpyenv virtualenv 3.9.16 mycoeiroinkをやるとエラーが出ます。それでみなさんにはこのダウンロードしたリポジトリをどうやって作動させるのかを教えて欲しいです。私のパソコンはMacbook m1チップです。私はまだプログラミング歴がめちゃめちゃ浅いので詳しくよくわかりません。よろしくお願いします！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「エラーが出た」だけでなく、最低限は「具体的なエラーメッセージ」を質問に含めてください。

Comment: zsh: command not found: pyenvと出ますね。

Comment: このソフトに関して知識が無いですが、質問者さんが参考にしている Zenn の記事で解説されているのは合成音声の声色（「mycoeiroink」というみたいですね）を**作る**方法です。
質問者さんが探しているのは既に有る声色を**使う**方法のようですから、読むべきものがちがうように思います。
使う方法は公式サイトにある[「使う」](https://coeiroink.com/mycoeiroink/installation)のページに解説が有るようです。

Comment: あの...Mac版をダウンロードしたところ開発者がわからないため開けられませんと表示されました。これどうしたらいいですか？一回旧バージョン使ってやってみますが。

Comment: 旧バージョン全て同じで開発者がわからないと言われました。

Comment: すみません。自己解決しました。

Comment: せめて、なにをどうやってそれを解決したのか、を自己回答しましょう

Comment: すみません。まず問題としては単純なものでした。まず最新のバージョンでは作動しなかったので１つ昔のバージョンをインストールしました。これは配布モデルの方ではなくmycoeiroinkのリポジトリです。それでデスクトップに落としたリポジトリを左クイックで見ると「開く」の下に「パッケージの内容を表示」と出てきます。このファイルの中に「models」というものがあるので入れたい配布モデルを１つずつ入れました。（たった２つでもモデルを一気に入れたらエラーが出る。）そしてmycoeiroinkのファイルを左クイックで「開く」を押すと作動しました。

Comment: なかなか苦戦しましたがなんとか１日以内に使えるようにはなりました。解決するまでの道のりがかなり複雑なためお返事を待って動かしていくと回答者様の時間をかなり奪っていたかもしれません。せっかく解決策を教えていただきましたが自己解決してよかったと思っています。今回は作動しなかったり、エラーが起こる回数が軽く１００は超えていたので